# VMWare API disconnect USB-Passthrough

Tags: c#, api, vmware

I am using VMWare Workstation (v11) to run a Virtual Machine for testing.
Now I'd like to pragmatically add and remove USB-devices attached to the system.

`using VMware.Vim;` I can connect to the server and query it. I can also remove devices like CD-Drives and other things. But I can't disconnect any USB-Passthrough-Device. I either get : "Invalid Config" or "Unknown Error" (most likely due to the lib being interopt and not transporting all information)

My current code:

```
using VMware.Vim;
var dongle =  devs.SingleOrDefault(i => i.DeviceInfo.Summary.Contains("Silicon"));
if (dongle != null) {
    var usbDongle = (dongle as VirtualUSB);
    usbDongle.Connected = false;

    var spec = new VirtualMachineConfigSpec() {
        DeviceChange = new[] {                                                                 
            new VirtualDeviceConfigSpec() {                                    
                Device = dongle,
                Operation = VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperation.remove,
            }
        }
    };

    vm.ReconfigVM(spec);
```

Neither Operation = "remove" or "edit" has any effect. I'm always getting some kind of error...

I appreciate any ideas!

Regards,

Corelgott